# When do variables get calculated on NGINX

Tags: nginx, geoip2

Declaring new variables such as `map` or geoIP2 are always on the the `http` context.

Lets say I need to check for location of an ip only on certain `location` block in my configuration,
does that mean that this variables related to the geoIP2 will be calculated in any connection established to the server or only when its get called?

I wondered how NGINX actually works, when do the variables get calculated?

example:

```
http{
    geoip2 GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb {
        $geoip2Country country iso_code;
    }
    map $geoip2Country $denyCountry {
        default  1;
        US  0;
    }
    
    location /zone/{    //the only location where I use the variable
        if ($denyCountry){
            return 444;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable is evaluated at the point its encountered in the configuration file.

Comment: Which means?
On every single connection made to server or only when its being used (on the location I mentioned)?

Comment: Only if every connection uses the variable. If the variable is used inside a specific `location` block on a specific statement, then it will only be evaluated when a request matches that `location` and the statement is evaluated.

Comment: Lets say I'm using geoIP2, which looks up for a country based on the client IP.
in this point the variable related to the GeoIP2 is declared on the `http` block.
Also I have a `map` that declares another variable based on that geoIP2 variable.

I have only one `location` block that uses the `map` variable..
So is it evaluated for any other connection outside that `location`?